# how to check if a file already exists in database?

Tags: mysql, database, file

trying to check to see if the file already exist but it doesn't work LINE 6

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{

$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
if (file_exists($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
      {
      echo $_FILES['userfile"]["name'] . " already exists. ";
      }else{
$fp= fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
}
//include 'library/config.php';
//include 'library/opendb.php';

$query = "INSERT INTO upload (name, size, type, content )
VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";

mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'); 
//include 'library/closedb.php';

echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";
} 
}
```

Comment: `file_exists` will check the _filesystem_ and will return true if a file (or directory) already exists _at the provided path_. See the [documentation](http://php.net/file-exists). It doesn't check against the database.

Comment: First `print_r($_FILES['userfile']['name']);` to see what you are checking and if it makes sense for your system.

Comment: ran that code and it displayed the document thats in the database

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you attempt to check the database for a file.

Comment: whats the best way to go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

`$_FILES['userfile"]["name']`

Make sure your opening quotes match the closing ones. Example valid strings are `"this"` and `'this'`, for example.

```
echo $_FILES['userfile']['name'] . " already exists. ";
echo $_FILES["userfile"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
// etc.
```

Comment: echo $_FILES['userfile']['name'] . " already exists. "; thats what  i have now doesnt work

Comment: Make sure the "userfile" part is right and make it echo file data to debug. Easiest is to use `echo '<pre>';print_r($_FILES);echo '</pre>';` Also, according to your code the file is searched in the directory this script resides.